# How to avoid casting in child classes in java

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I would like to do a conversion from one model:

```
public class AnswerDto { }

public class AnswerMapDto extends AnswerDto {
   private Map<String, String> values;

   public Map<String, String> getValues() {
      return values;
   }

   public void setValues(Map<String, String> values) {
    this.values = values;
   }

}
```

to another:

```
public interface Answer { }

public class AnswerMap implements Answer {
   private Map<String, String> values;

   public Map<String, String> getValues() {
      return values;
   }

   public void setValues(Map<String, String> values) {
    this.values = values;
   }

}
```

I did it in the way that I created converter for each child and within this converter casting is necessary. Do you know how can I avoid such casting?

```
public class AnswerMapConverter implements AnswerConverter {

   @Override
   public AnswerDto toDto(Answer answer) {
      AnswerMapDto answerMapDto = new AnswerMapDto();
      answerMapDto.setValues(((AnswerMap) answer).getValues());
      return answerMapDto;
   }

   @Override    
   public Answer toModel(AnswerDto answerDto) {
      return new AnswerMap(((AnswerMapDto)answerDto).getValues());
   }
}
```

After some comment I realized to mention that there will be another child classes with diffrent return type of the getValues() method. For example.

```
   public String getValues() {
      return values;
   }
```

Comment: I'm amazed calling a non-existing method your code still compiles. you don't have a setValues method in AnswerMapDto, let's start with that.

Comment: On top of what @stultuske mentioned, the `getValues` methods are all in the implementing classes? If these were defined by the interface, no casting will be needed.

Comment: @Stultuske - of course I have this method but I thouth it's not neccessary to put it here cause it's not important for the question

Comment: @KoinArab you are asking about the type of parameters it take, yet showing the method itself (including the parameters) you consider irrelevant?

Comment: Do you have a method `Map<String, String> getValues()` in the interface `Answer` that is implemented in the child classes?

Comment: @KennethAngeloReyes i didn't mentioned it here - getValues method have a diffrent return types in each subclass

Comment: "_but I thouth it's not neccessary to put it here_", "_ i didn't mentioned it here , getValues method have a diffrent return types_", I think you're not mentioning some stuff that you think are irrelevant but they actually arent.

Comment: @Stultuske Matteo NNZ - right, I should add these information. I edited the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `answer` and `answerDto` are both objects of the interface, not the implementation class. You do not need a conversion if the interface declares the functions `getValue` and `setValue`.

Additionally you can create an interface `HasValue<T>` which has the functions `public T getValue()` and `public void setValue(T value)`, and let `Answer` and `AnswerDto` implement this interface. Doing so you need to write the code only once.

Comment: Thank you. That generic, additional interface was what I needed. I'm also glad that compared to other guys you give me a chance to fill the missing information in question ;)

Comment: The others succesfully reviewed your question, I just answered assuming your question will be changed according to the review. Just 2 different parts of working on your question :)

Comment: That's not true. Reviewing question should let the author to provide a fixes. Downvoting and requesting for a question closing is something different.

Comment: Do not take it personally. Reading the first comments I was not sure whether the question will be fixed either. There are many questions which do not fullfill the standards, without closing them SO would overflow with bad questions and become useless. 

And I also received multiple downvotes in the past, receiving negative reputation motivates me to become better. Comments can be ignored, negative reputation needs to be minimized.